# Elementary integrals and Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

An article of Brian Conrad "[Impossibility theorems for elementary integration](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf)" says that a way of proving the following elliptic integral

> If $P(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $\ge 3$ without repeated roots, then $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ P(x)}}$$ 
>   is not an elementary integral.

After that, Conrad says that this theorem is a consequence of general facts about compact Riemann surfaces, because the formula obtained by the Liouville theorem for elementary integrals is equivalent to the equality for meromorphic $1$-forms

$$\left({dy}/{y}\right)=\sum c_j (dg_j)/(g_j)+dh$$

on the compact Riemann surface associated to $y^2=P(x)$, and for degree of $P>2$ the left side of the formula is a holomorphic $1$-form on $C$, and a non-zero holomorphic 1-form on a compact Riemann surface never admits an expression like the above expression.

I don't know anything about Riemann surfaces, and my question is: where can I find the information to understand this reasoning? I don´t know if this it's very difficult or it's very elementary in the theory of Riemann surfaces. I appreciate any answer. Thanks

Comment: Make some research on [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) and the compact Riemann surface $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 2):

Davenport, James, On the integration of algebraic functions. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 102. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1981.

J. Ritt, Integration in finite terms, Columbia UP, 1948.

Hardy, G. H. The integration of functions of a single variable. Reprint of the second edition, 1916. Hafner Publishing Co., New York, 1971.